# My Xamarin.Android app can't be started anymore via intent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

A few months ago my app was working fine when it gets started by an intent from another app. 
Now when my app gets started via intent I get the error:

```
03-21 12:00:43.096  Google Pixel 3 XL   Info    1234    ActivityManager Showing crash dialog for package com.comp.myapp u0
03-21 12:00:43.085  Google Pixel 3 XL   Error   5860    AndroidRuntime  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <c282b05120ba4b698b1a1e9d68af4131>:0 
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <e2a51596e3434d12a5bd106b9a0f0644>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <e2a51596e3434d12a5bd106b9a0f0644>:0 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <e2a51596e3434d12a5bd106b9a0f0644>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.6(intptr,intptr)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  Force finishing activity com.comp.myapp/md5ac266b5641403f314bbc23831457c9e5.MainActivity
```

This crash seems to happen before my app runs the `OnCreate()` method as I don't find what I log via `Log.Debug()` in LogCat.

My app works without problems, when I start it directly. In that state it also has no problems taking intents from other apps and processing them appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my OnCreate method wasn't started because it was:

```
    async public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
```

instead of

```
    async protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
```

Comment: please accept your solution as an answer. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!